# Replace with empty space

Tags: java

I have done this before, but now I encounter a different problem. I want to extract just the digits at the end ***"Homework 1: 89"***, which is in a *.txt file. As said I usually used* ".replaceAll("[\D]", "")"* . But if I do it ths time, the number before the colon (1 in example) stays... I cannot see of any solution.

it Should look like this:

```
       while (dataSc.hasNextLine()) {
              String data = dataSc.nextLine();
              ArrayData.add(i, data);

         if (data.contains("Homework ")) {
            idData.add(a, data);
            idData.set(a, (idData.get(a).replaceAll("[\\D]", "")));
```

Output being, A new string with Just "89"...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code your trying, the input, output and expected output please. We can help much more if you do that. Thanks

If I understand what you want, you can simply delimit by ": " and get the second token. If line="Homework 1: 89" then you can do `line.split(": ")`and it will be the second element of the returned array.

Comment: I think you should take a look at regular expressions, since they may be an essential part of your homework: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for editing your question.

If you are simply trying to get the end whenever there is the word homework and you can count on the consistent format you can do the following:

```
String[] tokens = data.split(": ");
System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```

So if your looking in your code you would be wanting to place this in your if statement where you are trying to get only the numbers after the colon from data.

What the code does it breaks your string into multiple components, breaking it whenever it sees ": ".

In your example of  "Homework 1: 89" it will break your data into two "tokens":

1:"Homework 1"

2:"89"

So when accessing the tokens array we access variable `tokens[1]` because the index starts at 0.

Comment: Well I see the logic behind, but I get a bit lost... Where exactly do I need to put the first line. I guess it is for general use throughtout the code, right?

Comment: @Heneko Expanded my answer, let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm.. so what I need to do is use your piece of code, and send just the token[1] to the ArrayList I want to store the value,
array.add(tokens[1]),

Comment: I believe so :) I'm not refreshed enough on java to know what your second line in your if statement does, but yeah, you will just need to do `idData.add(tokens[1]);`. If it works and you like it, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
1) String str="Homework 1: 89";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        2) String str="sdfvsdf68fsdfsf8999fsdf09";
           String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        System.out.println(numberOnly);
```

Comment: How does it solve OP problem? It is exactly same way as OP was doing it by now. You just rewrite `[\\D]` to `\\D` or `[^0-9]` which in this case represents the same.